# tabBarOnPress not working in react navigation tabs in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, tabnavigator

I am using nested navigation drawer > tab > stack navigators.

navigators are working but when i tap on tab item its throwing the following error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating '_ref4.route')
>   _getOnPress
>       TabView.js:110:44
>   _handleOnPress
>       TabBarTop.js:127:31 onPress
>       TabBar.js:466:33
>   _callTimer
>       JSTimers.js:156:15 callTimers
>       JSTimers.js:411:17
>   __callFunction
>       MessageQueue.js:302:47 
>       MessageQueue.js:116:26
>   __guard
>       MessageQueue.js:265:6 callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
>       MessageQueue.js:115:17

I am stuck here i tried many thing but no success

here is my code

DrawerNav.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DrawerNavigator} from 'react-navigation';
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import stackNav from './stackNav';


const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({
    DrawerItem1: {
        screen: stackNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: "Drawer Item 1",
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="rocket" size={24} />
        },
    },
    DrawerItem2: {
        screen: stackNav,
        navigationOptions: {
            drawerLabel: "Drawer Item 2",
            drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name="rocket" size={24} />
        },
    }
});


export default Drawer;
```

TabNav.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TabNavigator, TabView } from 'react-navigation'
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import MainScreen from './screens/MainScreen';

const tabNav = TabNavigator({
    TabItem1: {
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:"Tab One",
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name={"glass"} size={30} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },

    TabItem2: {
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:"Tab Two",
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name={"glass"} size={30} color={tintColor} />
        }
    },

    TabItem3: {
        screen: MainScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarLabel:"Tab Three",
            tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <Icon name={"glass"} size={30} color={tintColor} />
        }
    }

    ///... add more tabs here

}, {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
        tabBarOptions: {
            activeTintColor: '#222'
        },
});


export default tabNav;
```

stackNav.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'
import IOSIcon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import DetailScreen from './screens/DetailScreen';
import MainScreen from './screens/MainScreen';
import tabNav from './tabNav'

const stackNav = StackNavigator({
    Main: {
        screen: tabNav,
        navigationOptions:({navigation}) => ({
            title: "Main",
            headerLeft:(
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
                <IOSIcon name="ios-menu" size={30} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ),
            headerStyle: { paddingRight: 10, paddingLeft: 10 },
        })
    },
    Detail: {
        screen: DetailScreen,
        navigationOptions: (props) => ({
            title: "Detail",
        })
    }
})

export default stackNav;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error with TabNavigator.

I also have executed the official react-navigation example (https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/examples/NavigationPlayground/js/SimpleTabs.js) with no success (same error).

My guess is that this is a bug of latest versions of Expo/React Native.

What versions are you using?

I'm using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^22.0.2",
    "react": "16.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-native": "^0.49.5",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.20"
  }
```

**Confirmed**: ejecting from Create React Native App solves the problem.
So, it seems to be a bug on Create React Native App or Expo.

Comment: "dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.17.1",
  "mobx": "^3.3.1",
  "mobx-react": "^4.3.4",
  "react": "16.0.0",
  "react-native": "0.50.3",
  "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.2",
  "styled-components": "^2.2.3",
  "react-navigation": "react-community/react-navigation#master"
 }

Comment: i am not using expo

Comment: I achieved to fix this issue by upgrading dependencies.
Now I'm using: expo@22.0.4, react@16.0.0-beta.5, react-native@0.49.5 and react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.21.
Try to use react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.21.

Comment: using react-navigation@1.0.0-beta.21 version solved the issue. thanks

Comment: is this working for react-navigation version 3.0? I am trying same syntax but could not get it run. please tell if you have any suggestions for refreshing currently chosen tab, in bottomTabNavigator.